# Какой JS-плагин лучше всего использовать для создания календаря?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой JS-плагин лучше всего использовать для создания календаря как на картинке?

Comment: `moment.js` для работы с датами, я этим пользуюсь

Comment: Это полная вкусовщина, на данный вопрос не возможно объективно ответить.

Comment: смотря какое предназначение будет у вашего календаря

Comment: Я бы взял за основу https://www.daterangepicker.com/